# case_when condition IN -R

Tags: r

I have a data set

I want to use case_when but I am not getting the result I am looking

```
data <- outputs %>%
  mutate(`Date` = as.Date(`Date`),
          case_when(`Date`>= joined & is.na(transfer) & is.na(promotion) ~ "joined",
                  ` Date`>= joined & ` Date` < transfer ~ "joined",
                   ` Date`>= joined & ` Date` < promotion ~ "joined",
                   ` Date`>= transfer & is.na(promotion) ~ "transfer",
                    ` Date`>= transfer & ` Date` < promotion ~ "transfer",
                     ` Date`>= promotion ~ "promotion"))
```

expected result:

[image]

Comment: You haven't included `output = ` before you start `case_when` within `mutate()`

Comment: and why are you using backticks with Date there is no special chars in the name

Comment: Please do not include data as an image. This makes it difficult for others to copy/paste your data. In addition we do not have your input data, so we do not know why the result is off.

Comment: `\`Date\`` is not the same as `\` Date\``. Don't use backticks unless you need to, as Abdessabour says. If you do, don't put extra whitespace in the backticks.